# Renaming SOME columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, format

I have a csv file which I get as a report and it's header looks like this:

```
ln;7,26;7,27;7,28;7,29;7,3;7,31;8,01;8,02;8,03;8,04;8,05;8,06;8,07;8,08;8,09;name
```

The numbers are supposed to be dates (so 7,29 is July 29, 7,3 is July 30). How can I convert these to actual date format if I'm using pandas? Since it's from a report, I'd need a way to format them daily automatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show what you tried. None of those contain the year, and that means datetimes will default to 1900

Comment: There's nothing noteworthy to show - I'm really new to python and pandas, just picked it up to make my job easier. The date could be 2018.

Comment: I assume that it should be `7,30`, not `7,3;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `pd.to_datetime`:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:-1] + ',2018', format='%m,%d,%Y')

DatetimeIndex(['2018-07-26', '2018-07-27', '2018-07-28', '2018-07-29',
               '2018-07-03', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-01', '2018-08-02',
               '2018-08-03', '2018-08-04', '2018-08-05', '2018-08-06',
               '2018-08-07', '2018-08-08', '2018-08-09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Just assign the result back:

```
c = df.columns.tolist()
c[1:-1] = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[1:-1] + ',2018', format='%m,%d,%Y')
df.columns = c
```

Unfortunately, the temp list is needed because `pd.Index` does not support mutable operations.

Comment: Thank you, its working! Although I modified it heavily. I'll post my version tomorrow if you're interested